# Transaction downloads are always nil

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, ios6

I'm working on an application for iPad. it has In App purchases of a **non-consumable** type. so I'm using **Hosted Content** feature provided by apple.
the problem is the '**downloads**' property for '**transaction**' is always '**nil**'

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        if (transaction.downloads) {
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];            
    }
}
```

I'm setting the state for the **application** in **iTunesConnect** as '**Developer Rejected**' and the status for the **in-app purchase product** is '**ready to submit**'.
the content for in-app purhcase product has been uploaded through **XCode**.

any help would be appreciated alot.
many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just the targeted iOS must be set to iOS6 (the OS on the device must be iOS6) ... so i updated the device and it worked perfectly